# submitHandler doesn't work

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, jquery-validate

The following code doesn't work.

```
$(document).ready(function(){ 
        $("#digitalchange").validate(
        { 
            rules: { 
             addbalance: {
                digits:true,
                min:20,
                max:1000

            },
             addquota: {
                digits:true,
                min:5,
                max:1000    

            }
         }, 
            submitHandler: function(){

      var var1=$("#addbalance").val();
        alert(var1);
        }
              messages: { 


            }
        }); 
     });
```

However, after I remove

```
submitHandler: function(){

          var var1=$("#addbalance").val();
            alert(var1);
            }
```

, the remaining code works. What's wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're missing a comma after the closing } of the submitHandler value function?

Answer (score 3):

should you have a comma after the sumbitHandler declaration?